# how could you get rid of dimples in DRIED oil based polyurethane?

Tags: finishing

the dresser was stained with oil based dark walnut,after it dried for days,applied oil based polyurethane,when dried seemed to have alot of small dimples or small bubbles,do i use fine steel wool or sandpaper?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackExchange. The SE format doesn't allow for duplicate Questions and you've asked about something that has been addressed from various different angles numerous times over the years. Did you try a search before asking?

Comment: Welcome to WSE. As Graphus pointed out this question has been answered before.  You can search and review previous similar questions when entering a question subject.  The site search algorithm will locate many similar questions that you can review first.  IF those do not lead to an answer feel free to enter your unique question.